# Is that possible to import all types from a file as a union in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare some types in a file and then import all of them as a union in other. I tried:

```js
// types.ts
export type Type1 = string;
export type Type2 = number;
export type Type3 = boolean;
```

```js
// other.ts
import * as Types from "./types";
const t: Types = 1;
//       ^ Cannot use namespace 'types' as a type.ts(2709)
```

It just simplely doesn't work.

I'm sure if it's possible to `import types into a union` or do I have to write a union manually to involve all the types explicitly?

Comment: I strongly doubt it's possible. What's the use case? Maybe we can help you solve the underyling problem in a different way.

Comment: I want to make a function like `fun<T extends keyof Types>(name:T, params:Types[T])`. This function accept a name and its associated param type. I may have a lot of such types and I'd like declare them in one file and the types maybe changed often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on why you need the union. If you declare the types like this then you can index them for your needs:

```js
type MyTypes = {
    f: string;
    g: number;
    h: boolean;
}

fun<T extends keyof MyTypes>(name: T, params: MyTypes[T]);
```

You can then get the union like this if desired:

```js
type UnionOfMyTypes = keyof MyTypes extends infer K
    ? K extends keyof MyTypes ? MyTypes[K]: never
    : never;
```

Comment: Use fields of type as carrier of other types? It looks like suit for my case.